# How to change MSDN install of Win Server 2003 so it will accept a volume license key

Tags: windows-server-2003, licensing

I installed a server with the wrong media (MSDN) I should have used the volume media. I know I can do a repair install with the volume media but would like to avoid this. Does anyone know a way to make this install be able to take the volume license key? I saw this article http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=328874 but it just makes it sound like it would change the key.

Comment: I don't know why someone gave me a down vote... I'm not talking about using non-legit volume keys. They are legit volume keys that are currently in use through out the environment. I rather just not to a repair and install to get this worked out.

Comment: Awesome now someone thinks this is off topic? This is one server out of 16 in an environment that I'm working on. Care to add a comment on why this off topic?

Comment: If you want to be totally compliant with your license terms, a re-install is the *only* option. Anything else is dodgy grounds if a Microsoft auditor comes knocking.

Comment: That is more then fine as the answer. I would think this would have be more constructive if someone would have posted that as the answer. The point of me asking this is to find out if there was ANY other option. Not only does it seem as there is not but people think this is a wrong question to ask.

Comment: Licensing alteration is a touchy subject on SF. We've had people in the past asking for non-legitimate reasons; @BenPilbrow can post his comment as an answer and you can accept it for him, if he sees this comment. Generally if something sounds like it may be tied to non-legitimate purposes with licensing there are a number of people that will downvote the question out.

Comment: I would hope from the rating that I have people wouldn't think I was trying to get one over on Microsoft and use volume licensing when I wasn't supposed too. Thanks for the comment though. I just accepted the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contact your Microsoft Volume Licensing person for assistance. They may have access to tools in assisting with this type of situation or maybe able to get you to the correct Microsoft resource.

Comment: This was one of the firs things that I did. Guess I should have said that. The tech told me the only thing I could do was use a MSDN key or do a in place upgrade. Since you at least tried to answer it I will just accept it as the answer. Thanks

Comment: Are there any software installation requirements preventing/discouraging you from either option?

Comment: I was located 3 hours from the server. I was hoping there was something I could do that would avoid me having to do a in place upgrade.

Comment: If there is an off-chance that this is a virtualized server, then an on-site visit for a re-installation/upgrade may not be necessary.